# When I use 'esign&registration' it makes the 'registration' true. When I use the ''esignandregistration' it makes the 'eSignAndRegistration' true

Tags: angularjs, parameters, ampersand, query-string

```
  eSignAndRegistration: boolean;
  registration: boolean;
  esign: boolean;
  css: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('registration')) {
      this.registration = true;
    } else if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('esign&registration')) {
      this.eSignAndRegistration = true;
    } else if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('esign')) {
      this.esign = true;
    } else if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('css')) {
      this.css = true;
    }
  }
```

Why is the '&' symbol doing that? How can I make it so that I can use 'esign&registration' making the boolean 'eSignAndRegistration' true.

Answer (score 0):

I added multiple conditions to the if statement and it got it working:

```
if (
  this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('esign') &&
  this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('registration')
) {
  this.eSignAndRegistration = true;
} else if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('registration')) {
  this.registration = true;
} else if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('esign')) {
  this.esign = true;
} else if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('css')) {
  this.css = true;
}
```